# How do I stop all my chrome tabs from reloading each time one of my extensions update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

This is a recent experience I've been having (~2-3 months). i.e. All my open tabs suddenly reload.

The other day I noticed that it happens when an extension of mine autoupdates. I know when this has happened because I use the extension: "Extensions Update Notifier". It also happens if I install a new extension.

This issue doesn't have to do with "discarding", I have already tried that possibility. None of my pages have been discarded and this is still happening.

Comment: Why not control when your extensions update ie outside of your working time.

Comment: I'll look into how to do that. More ideal would be if I could have an option for extensions to still auto-update... but wait until chrome is reloaded in order to integrate those changes (which I'm assuming is why tabs are reloading now, because its assumed I want the new extension features right away). Or even better, an option to intentionally reload all my tabs to integrate extension changes... Rather than just immediately doing it each time one updates or gets installed.